# Matrix Distance Genetic Algorithm on Android

Tags: php, android, json, algorithm, genetic

I am making a routing application on Android when user can input the amount of hours to travel a place and my application would give an output of possible route users can travel.

I am using genetic algorithm (GA) to give the route to the user, and I use PHP to execute my GA.

Here comes the problem, in order for routing to be effective, I need to know distance between each city to verified if the route is possible and the distance in minimized. How to store distance between each city in order to make the execution faster? I have tried to get the distance **directly**
 from Google Maps API but it takes longer execution time.

I was thinking to store the distance to json file, but is it possible? Or is there another effective ways?

**Note that the destination will be dynamic. Users can add a new destination, so whenever there is a new destination the matrix distance needs to be updated.**

Please help me :) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You know the initial position of the user and want to know different destination distances. I suggest you to use single source shortest path deterministic algorithm like [Dijkstra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm) instead of evolutionary algorithm. The implementation based on a min-priority queue implemented by a Fibonacci heap running in O(E.logV) where E is the number of edges and V is the number of vertices. It runs much faster than genetic algorithm and also find the best answer instead of some approximate one. It also has the property that finds the first nearest destinations first which is suitable for you.

Comment: Hi Alireza, but is it possible to use Djikstra to find the possible route in the amount of times? Plus where would I store the distance between city on Djikstra?

Comment: @Listiani whenever you need the proper distance run the algorithm. Also you can have dynamic heap for keeping edges